# Make python code continue from line where exception was raised

Tags: python, exception

I wonder if there is any way to catch exception in python other thn try catch, which helps to continue from line where exception was raised. for example.

```
try:
    do something 1
    do something 2
    do something 3
    do something 4
except Exception1:
    do something
except:
    do something for all other exception
```

In above if any exception occur at do something 2. it will catch exception do something accordingly , and exit block.

But I want it catch exception and perform some action and start execution from do something 3.

One way I can think to achieve this is add try except for each line, or convert that each line into function and apply decorator to handle exception. But I don't feel like that would by nice to do. Like if you have 100 action to perform, you won't make 100 function or add 100 try catch.

There must be some way to handle this, may be by creating handler for exception. But I don't understand how. Thanks if you can help.

Note: I don't have any requirement right now for this. This is just out of curiosity. If this is possible to achieve in better and simple way.

**Edit: Guys this is not duplicate question. I have already checked.**

I want to know if there is a way like I did to catch sigint and sigterm signals.

```
class GracefulKiller:
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self,signum, frame):
        print("Program was killed externally.")
```

If we can create handler for Exception like for example ValueError. and continue from line which raise that exception.

Comment: An exception *exits that block*. Put separate `try...except` handlers around each statement if the next one can continue when a preceding one raised an exception.

Comment: Yes that is one case. But if you have 100 or 1000 action to perform. Is it the only way, by adding try and except for each exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not duplicate question. I have already checked.

Comment: No, there are no other options. The duplicate already covers the options you have.

Comment: If you have 1000 sequential operations to be done, each of which could fail without impacting all subsequent ones, then you should probably be constructing your code differently or creating a domain specific language. If you have to chain even 100 try/catch blocks together, your implementation is probably a bad idea.

Comment: You could always loop through a 1000 statement list using `eval` in a try/catch block, but you shouldn't.